# C++ pointers value changing

Tags: c++, linux, pointers

Hello I have simple code like this

```
void func(int &x, int y, int* z){
    int a = 3;
    int b = 1;

    cout << *z << endl;
    x = *z + b;
    cout << *z << endl;
    y = *z + x;
    z = &a;

    cout << "func: x = " << x << endl;
    cout << "func: y = " << y << endl;
    cout << "func: *z = " << *z << endl;
    cout << "func: a = " << a << endl;
    cout << "func: b = " << b << endl;

    return;
}

int main(){
    int a = 2;
    int b = 4;

    func(b, a, &b);
    cout << "main: a = " << a << endl;
    cout << "main: b = " << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And for output I get

```
4
5
func: x = 5
func: y = 10
func: *z = 3
func: a = 3
func: b = 1
main: a = 2
main: b = 5
```

So my question is, for what reason the value of *z changes after `x = *z + b` because I can't figure it out by myself.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is a reference to the `b` in main (not to be confused with the `b` in func, which is separate). `z` is a pointer to the `b` in main. References are basically pointers, but without the `*` or `&` syntax, and you can't make them point to something else (there's no equivalent to `z = &a` for references).

The line:

```
x = *z + b;
```

is basically doing:

```
b_in_main = b_in_main + b_in_func;
```

because both `x` and `*z` refer to the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you use & before an argument you give to a method, it becomes not copied but **linked to it**.

So that:

1. You change x which is linked to b
2. z changes corresponding to b's new value, because it's linked to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = *z + b;
```

changes the value of z because:
- here, x is an int reference pointing to your caller-side variable b
- z is an int pointer containing the address of the same variable b
Therefore, at this point, x and z refer to the same thing.
Therefore, assigning a new value to x means assigning that value to b. Since z points to b, reading z afterwards gives you the value you assigned to x.

You can make sure of this, for instance by writing and comparing the address of x, and the value of z:

```
cout << "(1) z is: " << z << " - &x is: " &x
// should be the same
z = &a;
cout << "(2) z is: " << z << " - &x is: " &x
// should be the different
```

In your context, the two values will be identical until you reassign z.

Answer (score 0):

Because you changed it to point to local variable a

```
z = &a;
```

Hence when you dereference it, it gives you value of local variable a, which is 3

Comment: I asked about other thing. Thanks for the answer, but this was not my question :)

Comment: didn't you ask why the value of *z changed after this line x = *z + b; ?

Comment: Yes but your answer in for something two lines below, which is not executed at the time of `x = *z + b` . I mean the two couts, in the first `*z == 4` after `x = *z + b` `*z == 5` .. the above answers are correct